# Nethogs ioctl failed while establishing local IP

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

When I tried to monitor my internet bandwidth with `nethogs`

```
$ sudo nethogs eth0
```

I got the following error:

```
ioctl failed while establishing local IP for selected device eth0. 
You may specify the device on the command line.
```

This is the output of `sudo ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen1000 link/ether 20:6a:8a:5d:5d:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWNqlen 1000
    link/ether 56:10:e4:e0:61:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global usb0
    inet6 fe80::5410:e4ff:fee0:61f1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:7c:8f:79:88:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Usually you get that answer when you try to monitor an interface which has no IP address assigned (probably not connected).

The output from `ip addr` shows that only one of your interfaces has an IP address, namely `usb0`.

So `sudo nethogs usb0` should finally give the desired result.

As there are comments mentioning different interfaces: if `ip addr` shows several interfaces with IP-addresses assigned there are two options for you:

- `ip route show | grep default` will show you the one device that is used to access "everything outside". e.g.
  `default via 192.168.0.253 dev eth1  proto static  metric 100` tells me I have to use `sudo nethogs eth1`
- If your goal is to look at internal traffic (within a local network or even between virtual machines on the same host) you *can* try with all devices found by `ip addr` or `ip link`.

Comment: Thanks. It was `sudo nethogs eth1` for me.

Comment: In my case, in 64 bit ubuntu 15.05, `usb0` is renamed as `wlp6s0`.

Comment: check which interface holds the main IP using `ifconfig` and then use it with `sudo nethogs <HERE>`